# Accessing inner elements in Couchbase with N1QL

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Firstly i am sorry if this question is sounding too stupid. But i am recently learning N1QL and need some output for my statement. My bucket name is MultiSiteResponseTime and I am trying to get the result of all the hours by executing "**select HourResponsetime.Hour from MultiSiteResponseTime;**". But i don't get any result. From what i have understood, if you want to access the inner elements then you have to use it like so **HourResponsetime.Hour** but i am not sure where i am wrong. Also if you could help me in getting result of a specific key, for example i would like to know the result of ResponseTime present for Hour 1.

```
{
  "Para": "ResponseTime",
  "Date": "18-04-2016",
  "Qantas": {
    "HourResponsetime": [
      {
        "Hour": 0,
        "ResponseTime": 8
      },
      {
        "Hour": 1,
        "ResponseTime": 9
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is by no mean a stupid question!

The dotted path syntax "`A.B`" works well when `A` is a **JSON Object**. Your document structure has an **array** of objects in `HoursResponseTime`, that's why it doesn't work. The way to go is to use an array index selector with an asterisk: `A[*]`.

Also, the path syntax starts from the root of the document's content. Here you have an intermediary object `Qantas`, which you should make part of the path.

This gives us:

```
SELECT Qantas.HourResponsetime[*].Hour FROM MultiSiteResponseTime;
```

This should return an **array of `Hour`s** for each document.

Comment: Thanks a lot Simon, i am getting the desired results. So correct me if i am wrong, i need to mention [*] asterix whenever i need to  access the contents of an array.

Comment: Yes if you want to collect the value of one attribute for all elements of the array. You can also get a particular element eg. [3]